# Max file size for create_compressed_fs tool

Tags: debian, udf, loop-device

Somebody knows what the maximum size of file could be processed by `create_compressed_fs` tool or used by `/dev/cloop` device? I suspect that it could be the root of the issue.

I created "ISO" (UDF) image with: `genisoimage --allow-limited-size` command and then passed it through the `create_compressed_fs`. But mounting on `/dev/cloop` is failed with reason:

`cloop: final offset wrong (73........ not 61........)`